# Using tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.audio_ops.audio_spectrogram to generate spectrogram

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to change the Length of the FFT？

```
  Args:
    input: A `Tensor` of type `float32`. Float representation of audio data.
    window_size: An `int`.
      How wide the input window is in samples. For the highest efficiency
      this should be a power of two, but other values are accepted.
    stride: An `int`.
      How widely apart the center of adjacent sample windows should be.
    magnitude_squared: An optional `bool`. Defaults to `False`.
      Whether to return the squared magnitude or just the
      magnitude. Using squared magnitude can avoid extra calculations.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor` of type `float32`.
    3D representation of the audio frequencies as an image.
```

The above is the parameter and return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the input tensor is the FFT length